# Can't find the internal implementation for Swift dictionary "keys" property

Tags: swift, dictionary, github

I'm currently studying `Dictionary` in Swift and am particularly interested in how

[image]

is implemented internally. I looked at Swift's GitHub project but could not find the page for Swift's dictionary type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of `Dictionary.keys` can currently be found in [HashedCollections.swift.gyb](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/df5358b94b9b8156b85ed83af6d5c159f4a53b6e/stdlib/public/core/HashedCollections.swift.gyb#L1995-L2010).

Comment: Thank you so much for helping out! One following up question if you dont mind, could you please tell me how you found the implementation of "Dictionary.key" among the hundreds of thousands of pages in swift github? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I grepped for `keys` in the `stdlib` directory. That gives a much smaller result set to look through.